# Passing Named Parameters via an intermediary script

Tags: powershell, parameters, scripting

I have two scripts:

Script1.ps1:

```
param(
[string]$WhoCares = "",
[string]$PassThrough = ""
)

#do a whole bunch of random stuff here...
.\Script2.ps1 $PassThrough
```

Script2.ps1:

```
param(
[string]$FirstParameter = "",
[string]$SecondParameter = ""
)

Write-Host "First Parameter is: " $FirstParameter "Second Parmeter is: " $SecondParameter
```

What I envision doing is something like:

Script1.ps1 -WhoCares one -Passthrough "-FirstParameter Test -SecondParameter Test1"

And then seeing:

First Paramter is Test Second Parameter is Test1

But What I am seeing is

First Parameter is -FirstParameter Test -SecondParameter Test1 Second Parameter is

which is, parameters I want to send to script2 are coming through as a string.  How to I pass parameters through an intermediary script

I don't want to modify Script1.ps1 to include every possible parameter, because im using Script1 to setup an environment, logging, etc.

Comment: Just use a -PassThru switch on Script2, it will inherit any variables defined in Script1 if you call it from Script1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change Script1 to splat the Passthrough parameters to Script2:

```
param(
[string]$WhoCares = "",
[hashtable]$PassThrough = @{}
)

#do a whole bunch of random stuff here...
.\Script2.ps1 @PassThrough
```

Then pass the Passthrough parameters to Script1 as a hashtable:

```
$Passthru =
 @{
   FirstParameter = 'Test'
   SecondParameter = 'Test1'
  }

  Script1.ps1 -WhoCares One -Passthrough $Passthru
```

Comment: Just to be clear, I think splatting requires v3+ iirc. But it is definitely the way to accomplish this.